# Diagonalizing, Eigenvalues and Eigenspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Prove that the matrix $A=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        2 & 0 & -2 \\
        0 & 3 & 0 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$ $ is diagonalizable and thus find the bases for the eigenspaces and
$P^{-1} AP$, where $P$ is the diagonalizaling matrix.

Only thing i know so far is that the eigenvalues are 2 and 3 and 2 has a dimension 1 and 3 has dimension 2. Not sure what to do after.

Comment: the matrix $P$ will consist of the eigenvectors; do you know how to calculate eigenvectors?

Comment: not sure how to. could you explain it?

Comment: See this pdf, for example, for an introduction to the topic: http://math.mit.edu/~gs/linearalgebra/ila0601.pdf

Comment: http://www.math.uconn.edu/~glaz/math2210s16/Section%20Handouts/sec5_3.pdf

Comment: Since it's an upper triangular matrix the eigenvalues are the values on the diagonal.

Comment: @William I invite you to delete your previous remark (it happens to me also do to such mistakes !), because it will disturb further readers.

Comment: @JeanMarie OK thanks haha. I just didn't want to look like I was hiding it, but you make a good point about future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly (as the matrix is upper triangular) the characteristic polynomial is $\;(t-2)(t-3)^2\;$ , so the matrix is diagonizable iff $\;(t-2)(t-3)\;$ is its *minimal* polynomial, and indeed:

$$(A-2I)(A-3I)=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&\!\!-2\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-1&0&\!\!-2\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}=0$$

**Added under request**: Let us first write

$$\lambda I-A=\begin{pmatrix}\lambda-2&0&2\\0&\lambda-3&0\\0&0&\lambda-3\end{pmatrix}$$

Now, upon substituting $\;\lambda\;$ for the eigenvalues, the above matrix becomes singular and we want, in each case, to find out its kernel or solution space of $\;(\lambda I-A)\vec x=\vec0\;$, which will be the eigenspace corresponding to that eigenvalue, so:

$$\text{For}\;\lambda=2:\;\;\begin{cases}2z=0\\-y=0\\-z=0\end{cases}\implies y=z=0\implies V_2=\text{Span}\,\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}\,\right\}$$$${}$$

$$\text{For}\;\lambda=3:\;\;\begin{cases}x+2z=0\end{cases}\implies x=-2z\implies V_3=\text{Span}\,\left\{\,\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}\;,\;\;\begin{pmatrix}\!\!-2\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}\,\right\}$$

Comment: what about the bases for the eigenspace?

Comment: What about doing some effort on your question?

Comment: Could you help me find it or possibly link me to something that shows how to do it since I don't really understand this

Comment: @Hector Read now the added stuff to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Solve $\ker (A - \lambda I)$ for $\lambda$, which will be your eigenvalues.
Then by defintion, the eigenvector for every eigenvalue solves
$$ Av = \lambda v \iff (A - \lambda I)v = 0.
$$
Solve this system for every $\lambda$ and you will obtain the columns for $P$. The inverse is calculated per usual.